# How to set the space between table view cell and removing white color for background contentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

how to remove white color between cells and corner  i used clear color for container view  but not removing white color.

i take the custom cell on table view.
cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius=10;

Answer (score 0):

Set UITableView style grouped. And set each cell in different section. Then add code below:

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //this is the space
    return 50;
}
```

To change color between cells you should do:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 5)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return v;
}
```

If you want to change color of the background you should set the color you need in cell.contenrView.backgroundColor.

Comment: Thank u...but i am asking for only for cell background